# How to connect MongoDB with node-red

Tags: mongodb, node-red

I have this flow [image: flow]

when I try to deploy my flows I get this message `Error: More than 1 database name in URL`

Here is my url : `mongodb+srv://username:password1234@cluster0.hx0l5.mongodb.net/capteurs?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: There are multiple Node-RED nodes that support MongoDB operations, please edit the question to make it clear exactly which one you are using.

Comment: Also include the version on both the Node and Node-RED you are using.

Comment: thank you @hardillb the problem is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to use mongoDB Atlas you must have the latest version of `node-red-node-mongodb 0.2.4`

Second you must properly configure your mongodb flow

Here is an example

[image: node-red flow]

`Host` we must fill in the name of the cluster example `cluster0.hx0l5.mongodb.net`

`database` the name of your database example `mydatabase`

`username` your username

`password` your password

Comment: Please remember to come back and mark you answer as accepted (accepted score better in search so others can find it easier)

Comment: i will do it @hardillb